# Understanding caching

Tags: magento-1.8, cache

## Synopsis

I've noticed constantly throughout forum threads, blog articles and Q&A many problems are caused through caching *not* being cleared.

I *think* I understand the basics with caching and indexing but i'm hoping someone with extensive knowledge could potentially clear this up for me.

I am not asking for information about `NginX` or `Varnish` and the likes, but specifically how Magento caches and indexes content.

There are times when I have physically removed the `var/cache` directory and let Magento rebuild it and things started to work.

## Cache Management

Within the Admin Console under `System > Configuration > Cache Management` we have:

- Flush Magento Cache;
- Flush Cache Storage;

Can someone explain to me what caching pools are flushed by the above buttons?

Within the grid there are several default levels of caching for:

- XML configuration (which i thought was just config.xml files but it seems is layout local.xml files included)
- Layout XML: why is local.xml not cached here?
- Collections data: exactly what is it that is being cached and where?
- EAV types and attributes: I presume this is to do with associating attributes to `catalog_product` or `customer`?

On top of this there is additional caching for CSS/Javascript and Images:

- Flush Catalog Images Cache;
- Flush CSS/JavaScript Cache;

What are the above buttons flushing and how are those caches built?

## Additional information

Can anyone explain any further information or link to an article that might help understand in more details how the caching works with Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19781/correct-method-of-flushing-caches-managing-the-compiler/21043#21043) might be very helpful to you if you want to understand magento cache.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because the linked answer appears to be a insightful response to my question.