# Flushing cache on the back-end does not delete all cache

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

For testing purposes, I had done some core changes to the following files and they worked fine.

- `/js/varien/configurable.js`
- `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php`

So after my test, I replaced back the original with the revised files.  After going through **Cache Storage Management**, and flushing all, I am still seeing all of my revision in place!

While looking through FileZilla at var/cache/ and it's sub-folders, flushing cache on the Back-end does **NOT** delete all cache in mage--0, mage--1, ... and mage--f.

I have to keep on pressing "Flush Cache Storage" to delete all.  How can you delete all cache at once? And even after emptying the folders, the changes do not roll back!

What else can I do to roll back to original, even though I have both original file in place?

Comment: If this is a production environment cache files might not fully be deleted because visitors are requiring a page that is recreating the cache items right away. The PHP file should not be cached however. The javascript file might also be cached client side.

Comment: Also, flushing the cache with the button doesn't completely clear out all the subfolders in var/cache/ as there's a lot of Zend and other stuff that is permanently cached when caching is enabled. If you want a true, full cache clean, you have to manually delete the subfolders. As to the JS file, that's cached client-side cached in the browser and a good couple of CTL-F5 in the browser should do a forced reload of Javascript and CSS.

Comment: @SanderMangel Thank you for the reply.  This is a test site. I am the only user. When I am clearing cache, I am not refreshing or visiting the front end. So why is this happening?   What can't I see the pages as they were originally?

Comment: @FiascoLabs Thank you for the reply. I did delete all cache under var/cache/.  In Chrome i tried F5 and CTL-F5 a couple of times and even turned to Explorer, which I never use and it showed the revised. :-(

Comment: Test server, file/folder permissions causing Magento to create cache in /tmp? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940458/cant-change-magento-base-url-stuck-in-cache/8947825#8947825 Something's caching it, Redis, opcache?

Comment: @FiascoLabs  While testing, is it advisable to turn off / disable all cache?  What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @FiascoLabs Problem solved by flushing all of the browser cache.  Meanwhile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940458/cant-change-magento-base-url-stuck-in-cache/8947825#8947825 is a great article. And also I found this article http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19781/correct-method-of-flushing-caches-managing-the-compiler, explaining it more in depth  Thank you all.

Comment: @user2774042 - Yes, run your development server with no caching at all and you'll find the bugs quicker. Go into cache management, disable all items. The Browser just needs to have a cache flush every time you update CSS/JS, and with modern browsers, it's fairly easy to get to the History deletion. (Everything, Cache, Active Logins)

Answer (score 4):

Flushing of the Magento Cache

There are a few options here, namely:

```
Checking the line items and submitting refresh from the Actions dropdown box
Clicking the Flush Magento Cache button, and
Clicking the Flush Storage Cache button.
```

and another way:

->SSH users can use the following command to flush Magento caches:

$ find ./var/cache -type f -delete

->FTP users can use the following command to cleanup Magento caches:

> mrm -r ./var/cache ; mkdir ./var/cache