# Uploading php.ini file breaks Magento (front end and back end)

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

When I click the link to edit a customer's details just get a blank page. The error log shows

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3072 bytes) in /data02/username/public_html/buyonline/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Payflowpro.php on line 534

I uploaded a php.ini file to increase the memory_limit - php_info() shows that the memory limit was successfully increased to 256M, but doing anything on the site gives the error

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 1077401299661

I deleted it and re-uploaded the php.ini file after clearing caches and disabling the compiler following advice at [Correct Method of Flushing Caches & Managing the Compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19781/correct-method-of-flushing-caches-managing-the-compiler]).
When I try to enable the compiler again I get a similar error:

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 338654716846

Changing the memory limit setting in the htaccess file has no effect.

Has anyone any further ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: what is the error for the exception that is printing after you modify php.ini ? check in var/report folder

Comment: "The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded" which is common to all instances.  @userpk

Comment: Full first line:
a:4:{i:0;s:78:"The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded";i:1;s:2684:"#0 /data02/username/public_html/buyonline/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)

Answer (score 1):

in .htaccess add php_value memory_limit 1G

Comment: The change doesn't show in phpinfo(), so presumably it hasn't changed the memory limit.  Or does php not detect changes set via htaccess?@Vijay-CyberLocker

Comment: at bottom define and check root file may be defined

Comment: Some missing here?