# AH00127: Cannot map HEAD... and Blank Page

Tags: magento-1.7, php, apache, apache2

I've a Magento 1.7 store in a dedicated Apache 2.4/Ubuntu host.
My site is breaking down for some hours since last week.
Site is not offline but showing blank pages.
When I see the problem I restart Apache, and site is up.
But site goes down in the next day, in high traffic hours (high traffic for me is 10 orders/hour).

Looking for log files I can see this AH00127 many times.
I think it happens when reloading the blank page.

```
[core:error] [pid 19744] (36)File name too long: [client mas.ked.xx.xxx:60403] AH00127: Cannot map GET /tag/index/save/product/2087/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy50b2NhZG92ZXJkZS5jb20uYnIvcHJhdG8tdmlvbGV0YS1jZXJhbWljYS5odGLa/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1fwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1YwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv/ HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://www.mysite.com.br/product_name.html/
```

PHP Error Log says only this error, many occurences:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isRequired() on a non-object in /var/www/includes/src/Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer.php on line 167
```

Anyone know what is happening here?

At a first glance I disabled Mage_Captcha in backend. But the errors keep same.

My Apache settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    DeflateCompressionLevel 2
    <Directory /var/www/>
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
        AddDefaultCharset Off
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com\.br
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.mysite\.com\.br/$1 [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badass_cover_all_mycontent\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_value memory_limit 256M
            php_value max_execution_time 120
            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
            php_flag session.auto_start off
            #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
            php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
            php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_security.c>
            SecFilterEngine Off
            SecFilterScanPOST Off
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            <IfModule mod_filter.c>
                SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
                BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
                BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
                BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
                SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
                Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
            </IfModule>
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            SSLOptions StdEnvVars
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            #Options +FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
            RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?minify/([^/]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ lib/minify/m.php?f=$3&d=$2
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
            RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/app/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/app/errors/>
        <FilesMatch "\.(xml|phtml)$">
            Require all denied
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/pkginfo/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/lib/>
        #Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/var/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/includes/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/media/>
        Options All -Indexes
        #<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        #   php_flag engine 0
        #</IfModule>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/downloader/>
        <Files ~ "\.(cfg|ini|xml)$">
            Require all denied
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Today I'll try to disable Mage_Captcha in XML file. Despite of doing this won't be easy to say if it works, but I expect the site stay showing up tomorow.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the cause is a bad mod_rewrite rule in your .htaccess possibly?

- https://serverfault.com/questions/388858/how-to-fix-file-name-too-long-error-in-apache2

Also, if you note the redundant GET URL in the log which may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server for the HTTP referer:

> /tag/index/save/product/2087/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy50b2NhZG92ZXJkZS5jb20uYnIvcHJhdG8tdmlvbGV0YS1jZXJhbWljYS5odGLa/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5kZXgucGhwL3RhZy9pbmRleC9zYXZlL3Byb2R1Y3QvMjA4Ny91ZW5jL2FIUjBjRG92TDNkM2R5NTBiMk5oWkc5MlpYSmtaUzVqYjIwdVluSXZjSEpoZEc4dGRtbHZiR1fwWVMxalpYSmhiV2xqWVM1b2RHMXMv
>   **/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aW5k** ...

But this in regards to the /product_name.html file which is not default Magento.

And you may want to consider disabling compilation and using an OPCode cache instead to remove the possibly headaches caused by it, it may also be the source of your issues.

- [is it safe to run magento compiler?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19231/is-it-safe-to-run-magento-compiler/19237#19237)

Also make sure you have the Log cleaning enabled in Magento's admin configured as it will help to clean out the generated captcha images. You can do this manually by simply removing all files under /media/captcha.

Comment: Hi B00MER, thanks for attention. I put my Apache settings to show how Rewrite Rules are defined. But I think Apache Restart should not have solved this error. Moreover my site has stopped (showed blank pages) when I was out, so without any manual update.

Comment: Maybe this rule could be a problem:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com\.br`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.mysite\.com\.br/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Could be a problem when doing internal requests via shell?

Comment: Best bet is turn as much logging as you can: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store