# Blank Admin after trying to install GoogleShoppingApi from github

Tags: magento-1.9, google-shopping

I am wanting to use the Google Shopping Api from the github link below

https://github.com/bluevisiontec/GoogleShoppingApi

I have tried multiple times and followed all instructions without issue, but am getting a blank page in Admin. Error says:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:72:"Mage registry key "_singleton/googleshoppingapi/observer" already exists";i:1;s:1329:"#0 /home5/username/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home5/username/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/goog...', false)
#2 /home5/username/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(22026): Mage::getSingleton('googleshoppinga...')
#3 /home5/username/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home5/username/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14363): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /home5/username/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /home5/username/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14241): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /home5/username/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18698): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /home5/username/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18228): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home5/username/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21056): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home5/username/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home5/username/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:17:"/index.php/admin/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename(Disable) extension from App > etc > moduels.
Clear cache and then Run Compilation.

Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Excellent. That worked!

Deleting the app>bluevisiontec folder let me back into Admin.
Then I deleted app>etc>modules>bluevisiontech.
Then I disabled Compilations, re-uploaded the missing files and logged out then back in to Admin and everything is there and working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the observer names defined in the `config.xml` should be unique and not the same. Although I could be wrong.

- https://github.com/bluevisiontec/GoogleShoppingApi/blob/master/app/code/community/BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/etc/config.xml#L99-L120

That said, I can't find any version this module supports, but see it's been recently updated.

Also, it could be the fact you are using compilation and the module doesn't support it.  It's also best to just use [APC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [Aoe_ClassPathCache](https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_ClassPathCache) module or using a new version of [PHP with an Opcode cache](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) already included, as compilation tends to break a few 3rd party modules.

- [is it safe to run magento compiler?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19231/is-it-safe-to-run-magento-compiler/19237#19237)

Comment: Well disabling Compilation definitely seemed to help. Everything works, EXCEPT I am getting an error when trying to manage products...

Instructions say to set a store view for Oauth, but I don't see those settings anywhere and instead get an error:

    a:5:{i:0;s:77:"Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"....

The error message is too long to post here, but starts out as posted.

I can't believe Magento doesn't have Google Merchant Feeds by default and it's really ruining my sales compared to the last platform I used.