# Warning: is_writable(): Unable to find the wrapper "unix"

Tags: enterprise-1.14, compilation

I am getting error

`Warning: is_writable(): Unable to find the wrapper "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP`

While I am trying to turn on the compilation in Magento. 

I can see this error message in system.log as well

```
Warning: is_writable(): Unable to find the wrapper "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?  in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 74.
```

What is this error?
How this can be fixed?

**ADDED content of local.xml**

```
<config>
  <global>
    <install>
      <date><![CDATA[Mon, 20 Apr 2015 05:56:22 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
      <key><![CDATA[6cbdf8e6a8761e27f8a18dddd8578a8f]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
      <db>
        <table_prefix><![CDATA[magento_]]></table_prefix>
      </db>
      <default_setup>
        <connection>
          <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
          <username><![CDATA[database_user]]></username>
          <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
          <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
          <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
          <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
          <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
          <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
          <active>1</active>
        </connection>
      </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: What version of PHP? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Comment: @B00MER : PHP Version 5.3.24

Comment: What type of hosting environment? LAMP, WAMP, XAMPP? etc.

Comment: @B00MER : XAMPP

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: I'm guessing it's Windows? Haven't seen anyone use XAMPP on Unix systems..

Comment: Actually I am getting this error on my live site. Live site has Linux server.

Comment: @AnshuMishra Take a closer look at your session handler and cache definitions in your `app/etc/local.xml` also I'd consider using an OPCode cache vs compilation. See: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19231/is-it-safe-to-run-magento-compiler/19237#19237

Comment: @B00MER : There is no cache and session handler is files.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your local.xml file ?

Comment: @Prateek : added local.xml file content

Comment: Just a thought, can you check if you have Redis installed on your web server ?

Comment: @Prateek : Yes, Redis is installed on my server.

Comment: Then, it's very probable that your session files are actually being handled by Redis, and Magento is trying to save them in system's tmp directory instead of var folder inside installation. check out this link if it helps : http://www.joshdavenport.co.uk/warning-is_writable-unable-to-find-the-wrapper-tcp-magento-memcached-and-sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is due to mis-configuration of Redis on the server.
It is fixed by re-configuration of Redis cache on the server.